# Push vs pull in reactive-banana

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp, reactive-banana

I am building a mediaplayer-like application using reactive-banana.

Let's say I want a `Behavior` that represents the currently selected track in
the track list.

I have two options: use `fromPoll` to get the current selection when it's
needed; or use `fromChanges` and subscribe to the selection change event.

I use the selected track `Behavior` only when the user presses the "Play"
button. This event is much more rare than a selection change.

Given that, I'd assume that `fromPoll` would be better/more efficient
than `fromChanges` in this situation. But the docs say that "the
recommended way to obtain `Behavior`s is by using `fromChanges`".

Does it still apply here? I.e. will the polling action be executed more
often than it is actually used (sampled) by the network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the current version (0.7) of reactive-banana, the `fromPoll` function actually creates a behavior whose value is determined by executing the polling action whenever *any* event happens *at all*.

In contrast, `fromChanges` will only update the behavior when the particular event given as argument has an occurrence.

In other words, in the current implementation, `fromPoll` is always less efficient than `fromChanges`.

Then again, I wouldn't worry too much about efficiency right now, because I haven't spent much time implementing suitable optimizations yet. Just use whatever is simplest now and save any efficiency issues for future versions of reactive-banana.